# Execution failed for task:'app:process debugmanifest'

Tags: android

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.0-alpha1) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38
    is also present at [com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31 value=(25.3.1).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:41 to override.
```

**what is this error pls  help**

Comment: I think both `build.gradle` have different min and max sdk.

Comment: @devesh add your app gradle file

Comment: have you updated you android studio

Answer (score 0):

This will get when your Manifest file and build.gradle have different min and target SDK version supports.

Answer (score 0):

In app level build.gradle file, add the following lines at the end of file.

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '26.0.0-alpha1'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and sync the project.